# Joomla extensions installation

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a question regarding Joomla extensions, there are three main types: components, modules and plugins. Is there a way to install all three extensions as one in a single installation process ?
Otherwise if we have a large extension that is composed of smaller segments (e.g. component, module and plugin) then we have to repeat installation process three times, once for every extension. That's quite complex and I would like to know, if there's possibility to install them all at once.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using a package (introduced to Joomla 2.5). Within this package, you can install as many components, modules and plugins as you wish. For more information on packages, have a read of the following from the Joomla Documentation site:

https://docs.joomla.org/Package

Answer (score 0):

For installing most extensions and most users, the procedure will be: 
-->Download the extension to your local machine as a zip file package. 
-->From the backend of your Joomla site (administration) select Extensions → Install/Uninstall. 
-->Click the Browse button and select the extension package on your local machine. 
-->Click the Upload File & Install button. 
-->Some extensions may provide further instructions on installation. ==Note that modules and plugins must be enabled before they will work.

There are numerous association which are giving Joomla extensions for developing your websites. You can get progerssive Joomla extensions at Comdev. Source: http://comdevjoomla.blogspot.com/